# Double connectedness of SO3 via action on S2

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, group-actions, orthogonal-matrices

I understand that $SO(3)$ is doubly-connected and has $SU(2)$ as simply connected double cover.

Now I am trying to understand if I can see this double-connectedness by looking at group actions.

Let us consider the natural action of $SO(3)$ on ${\Bbb S}^2$. Is there a way that I can understand the double-connectedness by looking at the orbits of this action? Or probably at the orbits of an action of a different space than ${\Bbb S}^2$.

I see a certain connection with [Group action on simply connected space with simply connected stabilizer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758637/group-action-on-simply-connected-space-with-simply-connected-stabilizer) but this question has never been answered.

Comment: By doubly connected do you mean $\pi_1(SO(3)) = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @ArcticChar: I confused a bit by your comment. You meant for all two connected components manifold $M$ we have $\pi_1 (M)=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: No, I am just unsure about the term doubly connected. Does it mean $\pi_2 = 0$? @C.F.G

Comment: Since every action by $SO(3)$ pulls back to an action by $SU(2)$ with the same orbits, the orbit structure cannot detect the fundamental group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\SO}{SO}$
I will give a proof of $\pi_1(\SO(3))\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2$ using the canonical action of $\SO(3)$ on $S^2$ and a bit of homotopy theory.

The canonical action of $\SO(3)$ on $S^2$ is transitive, so it gives a surjection
$$
\pi\colon \SO(3)\to S^2;\quad g\mapsto g
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The inverse image of $x\in S^2$ is the stabilizer of $x$, which is a coset of $\SO(2)\subset \SO(3)$.
Therefore $\pi$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $\SO(2)$.
Consider the Serre exact sequence:
$$
\pi_2(S^2)\xrightarrow{\delta} \pi_1(\SO(2))\to \pi_1(\SO(3))\to \pi_1(S^2).
$$
We use the following facts:

- $\pi_2(S^2)\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the class of the map
  $$
  p\colon D^2\to S^2;\quad
  \begin{pmatrix}
  r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta
  \end{pmatrix}\mapsto
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \sin(r\pi)\cos\theta\\
  \sin(r\pi)\sin\theta\\
  \cos(r\pi)
  \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
- $\pi_1(\SO(2))\simeq \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the class of the map
  $$
  q\colon [0,2\pi]\to \SO(2);\quad \theta\mapsto R_\theta=
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \cos \theta&-\sin \theta\\
  \sin \theta&\cos \theta
  \end{pmatrix}.
  $$
- $\pi_1(S^2)=0$.

It remains to prove $\delta[p]=2[q]$.
Consider the map
$$
f\colon D^2\to \SO(3);\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
R_\theta&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(r\pi)&0&\sin(r\pi)\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin(r\pi)&0&\cos(r\pi)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
R_{-\theta}&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
One can easily check that the action of $f(x)\in \SO(3)$ on $S^2$ sends the basepoint $
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\-1
\end{pmatrix}\in S^2
$ to $p(x)$.
By the construction of the Serre exact sequence, $\delta[p]$ is given by the class of the map
$$
[0,2\pi]\to \SO(2);\quad \theta\mapsto f
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta\\ \sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}
=R_{2\theta},
$$
so we get $\delta[p]=2[q]$.